# on deploy: en_US/jquery/jstree/themes/classic/style.css" file can't be read

Tags: magento2

I'm getting this error when I do:

```
"bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f"
```

but the website works fine, what does it mean?

```
In File.php line 151:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  The contents from the "/var/www/magento/pub/static/frontend/Mytheme/custom/en_US/jquery/jstree/themes/classic/style.css" file can't be read. Warning!file_get_contents(/var/www/magento/pub/static/frontend/Mytheme/custom/en_US/jquery/jstree/themes/classic/style.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be an permission error. Give permission to var, generate and pub folder.

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 var/ generated/ pub
```

Comment: I thought it was a permission error but I did also run this code but it's still showing the thick error `#0 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php(144):`

Comment: oh I ran it again and it worked! thank you